# How do you go about starting up a rails app from a github source when they don't include a gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, terminal, gemfile

How do you go about starting up a rails app (Be able to $prompt "rails s" in terminal and run on localhost:3000) from a github source when they don't include a Gemfile? Do I have to create my own? If so can we use a generic one? I was trying to create a question and answer site for a project I'm working on and wanted to check out

https://github.com/membrain/T002_rails-overflow/

and

https://github.com/nsanta/openoverflow

but I was stuck on how to start them and wanted to ask how I should go about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are really old rails 2 apps, created before bundler existed so no Gemfile; if you look in `config/environment.rb` you'll see some gems specified and the instructions to run `rake gems:install` - but you need to install the older version of rails first

those code bases are very old and I would avoid if possible, note the last commit on each is 5 years ago